# output a list of concatenated strings

Tags: java, arrays, string, loops

I'm trying to implement a method that uses multiple String[] arrays to print a wordlist which contains every possible combination of the Strings in the arrays, in order and using max. 1 String of each array.

example:  `{"this" | "that"} {"is" | "was"} {"cool" | "lame"}`

```
String[] array1 = {"this", "that"};
String[] array2 = {"is", "was"};
String[] array3 = {"cool", "lame"};
```

should be used for the following output:

```
thisiscool
thatiscool
thiswascool
thatwascool
thiswaslame
thatwaslame
thisislame
thatislame
```

I've been experimenting with nested for-loops:

```
String out1 = "";
for(int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
            out1 = array1[a];
            System.out.println(out1);
            for(int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
                out1 += array2[b];
                System.out.println(out1);
                for(int c = 0; c < array3.length; c++) {
                    out1 += array3[c];
                    System.out.println(out1);
```

This didn't work well though. Maybe there's a better approach to this?

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow! You seem to be under the impression that StackOverflow is a site where you post a problem and get some code in return. This is in fact not the case. Your question will most likely be closed or even deleted shortly. To prevent this from happening in the future, please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [take a look at the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help). In particular, [make yourself famlilar as to what is regarded as on-topic around here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Share your code, no matter the qualify forst, it shows your effort

Comment: sorry about that! here's my code.

Comment: Is the number of String[] constant like 3 or can there be any number of such arrays?

Comment: Would the length of all arrays be the same?

Comment: it should work for any number of arrays and also different lengths.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**@Supercool.** has already left a perfect answer.
But as your opinion, I've been trying to figure out **if there's a better way to visualize than nested for-loops**, and I've come up with a way to "[recursive call](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science))"

By using a '`double array`' and '`recursive`',
although you add a new array, **you don't have to write an additional for-loop**.

Like this

```
public class StackOver
{
    static String[][] array = {{"this","that"},
                              {"is","was"},
                              {"cool","lame"},};

    public static void recString(String[][] a, int index, String output) {
        //make break-point
        if(index == a.length) {             //if 'index' reached to the end of array 'a'?
            System.out.println(output);     //print out string 'output' that collected so far
            //output should be = (a[0][?] + a[1][?] +...+ a[length-1][?])
            return;                         //And end the method.
        }

        // if 'index' didn't reach to the end of array :: 
        //If there's an array that hasn't been explored yet,
        for(int i = 0; i < a[index].length; i++) {
            recString(a, index+1, output + a[index][i]);
            //Add 1 to 'index' and add String out put that added '[index][i]' 
            //as parameters and call this method again.

            //This form is called recursive call!
        }
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        String t = "";

        recString(array,0,t);
    }
 }
```

[image]

Even if the array changes, with recursive calls, 
you can examine every array without changing the code and draw possible combinations.

Ex).

```
static String[][] array = {{"I","You","They"},
                               {"love","hate"},
                               {"me","you"},
                               {"too","either"},};
```

*Well, the grammar is a little awkward, but it's an example of stretching the arrangement a little bit longer.*

[image]

Comment: @c0rnfl4k3s I am very glad that my answer could give you a help!!! I hope you have a peaceful day!

Answer (score 2):

```
   String[] array1 = {"this", "that"};
   String[] array2 = {"is", "was"};
   String[] array3 = {"cool", "lame"};
   String text="";
   for(int a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
        text=array1[a];
        for(int b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
            text+=array2[b];
            for(int c = 0; c < array3.length; c++){
                System.out.println(text+array3[c]);
            }
            text=array1[a];
        }
   }
```

> Demonstration of same logic in JS

Run the following snippet

```js
let array1 = ["this", "that"];
let array2 = ["is", "was"];
let array3 = ["cool", "lame"];
let text="";
for(let a = 0; a < array1.length; a++) {
    text=array1[a];
    for(let b = 0; b < array2.length; b++) {
        text+=array2[b];
         for(let c = 0; c < array3.length; c++){
              console.log(text+array3[c]);
         }
         text=array1[a]
    }
}
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: actually, if it's done this way, the variable "text" doesn't have to be overwritten in every loop. it will produce the same output if it's only done in the third one

Comment: also, maybe there's a better way than nested for-loops? Because this requires another for-loop for every additional array